# Copy (or Paste) only CSS / Less selectors, without the containing declarations

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, copy, less, paste

In Visual Studio Code: I was wondering if there is a way to copy some CSS (or better: Less) code from one file to another but remove all declaration, but keeping the selectors. So basically only the code structure, not the values.

Something like this:

COPY THIS...

```
.myvlass1 {
  color:red;
  width:100%;
}
#myselector {
   font-size:16px;
   margin: 10px;
}
```

TO:

```
.myvlass1 {

}
#myselector {

}
```